# Convert HMR to GeoTiff

Tags: geoserver, gdal, java, geotiff-tiff

I've got gigs of .hmr raster files from our customer and I need them to be converted into GeoTiffs or something else which can be nicely imported into Geoserver system. I wonder if I can do it with GDAL tool and how?

Preferably I'd use gdal java library, but haven't look into that yet and don't know if that's even possible.

Greetz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be out of luck, HMR seems to be a proprietary Bentley format that isn't supported by GDAL. There are some that say it's little more than a compressed 8-bit TIFF, but that's about all I've found out about it.

If you are able to hack the format sufficiently so you can extract georeferencing and imagery, then you can use the GDAL API to programmatically output a GeoTIFF or any other GDAL format, but you're going to have to do the hard work yourself or pay/convince someone else to do it for you.

Not much of an answer, I know.

Comment: It is also NOT supported by ESRI's Data Interoperability suite (which is built on FME - so count that out as well).

Comment: Just for clarification, the HMR file format supports multiple different pixel types and compressions, not just 8 bits. Yes, will will need to use the Bentley tools to convert to another raster format that supports all types of images you have in your HMR files now. Tiff or GeoTiff are good choices.

Comment: I can confirm that Esri still doesn't handle `.hmr` natively with its raster conversion tools, although I can `Data > Export` to a `.tiff` from ArcMap. If I ever have to do batch conversions I plan to try running the tool from Python and seeing if it will handle it anyways, but can't justify spending the time for my current project.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully you've still got a Bentley Microstation / Decartes License?

Perhaps use the Batch conversion facility within that software and let it do the hard yards?

Comment: Yes, we will probably have to convert it from inside Microstation. Thanks.